# Is there an easy way to add a column to a Bootstrap horizontal definition list?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am looking for a way to do:

```
dt content | dd content | additional column
```

Is this possible with dl-horizontal?  Or do I need to change to divs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your additional column is part of the definition of the term, you can nest a row with columns inside the `<dd>` like this:

```
<dd>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">dd content</div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">additional column</div>
    </div>
</dd>
```

That will give you two equal columns that don't collapse on small screens. Change `xs` to `sm` or `md` if you want your additional column to appear below the dd content on small screens.

Comment: Thanks for the fast solution!  Don't know why I didn't see that.